# Maven plugin .jar failure

Tags: hibernate, build, maven

I'm trying to use maven to build hibernate 3.6.1 and I have this error :

```
  [WARNING] The POM for org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[DEBUG] org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0:
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of C:\Users\Se\.m2\repository\org\jboss\maven\plugins\maven-jdocbook-style-plugin\2.0.0\maven-jdocbook-style-plugin-2.0.0.jar from [central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0, locally cached artifact up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/maven/plugins/maven-jdocbook-style-plugin/2.0.0/maven-jdocbook-style-plugin-2.0.0.jar
[DEBUG] Reading resolution tracking file C:\Users\Se\.m2\repository\org\jboss\maven\plugins\maven-jdocbook-style-plugin\2.0.0\maven-jdocbook-style-plugin-2.0.0.jar.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file C:\Users\Se\.m2\repository\org\jboss\maven\plugins\maven-jdocbook-style-plugin\2.0.0\maven-jdocbook-style-plugin-2.0.0.jar.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[ERROR] The build could not read 21 projects -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.hibernate:hibernate-parent:pom:3.6.3.Final in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.hibernate:hibernate-parent:pom:3.6.3.Final in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.hibernate:hibernate-parent:pom:3.6.3.Final in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 29, column 13
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.hibernate:hibernate-parent:pom:3.6.3.Final in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 29, column 13
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:2.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.jboss.maven.plugins:maven-jdocbook-style-plugin:jar:2.0.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) @

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:339)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:632)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:581)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:233)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.hibernate:hibernate-manual:3.6.3.Final (C:\Users\Se\Desktop\Cluster\hibernate-distribution-3.6.3.Final\project\hibernate-documentation\manual\pom.xml) has 1 error
```

Answer (score 5):

Try add JBoss artifact and plugin repository to settings.xml or pom.xml.

> ```
>  <repositories>
>    <repository>
>      <id>JBoss Repo</id>
>      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
>      <name>JBoss Repo</name>
>    </repository>
>  </repositories>
>
>  <pluginRepositories>
>    <pluginRepository>
>      <id>JBoss Repo</id>
>      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
>      <name>JBoss Repo</name>
>    </pluginRepository>   
>  </pluginRepositories>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the version of hibernate-parent at http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-parent/ you're trying to download. Configure settings.xml for maven to include repo which hosts the required artifact.